# Problems with form validation. Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble with my form validation logic in my year one Javascript project.

Specifically with my errors reporting with the events.

The page randomly refreshes when I'm testing for "no username entered" etc.
Some errors will display for a moment and disappear.

Any help would be much appreciated, and will contribute to fixing the overall problem.

```
<body onload="setup()">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="page-header" class = "row">
        <div class="col-lg-12"> 
            <img id="banner" src = "pictures/homepage/banner.jpg" width = "100%" height = "20%"></img>
        </div>
        <p id="charc">Charcoal</p>
    </div>
    <div class="butts">
        <button onclick="dropdown()" class="button">Categories</button> 
        <button class="button">My Account</button>
        <button class="button">Shopping Cart</button>
        <button id="loggedIn-Out" class="button">Login/Register</button>
    </div>
    <div id="myDropDwn" class= "dropContent">
        <a href = "#"> womens </a>
        <a href = "#"> mens </a>
        <a href = "#"> shoes </a>
        <a href = "#"> accessories </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="login-page" class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form">
        <form id="logForm" class="login-form">
            <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
            <div id="login-user-error" class="errorReps"></div>

            <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
            <div id="login-pass-error" class="errorReps"></div>

            <button onclick="loginUser()">Login</button>
            <div id="login-error" class="errorReps"></div>
            <p class="loginMessage"> Not Registered? <a href="#">Register</a>
            <br>
            <br>
            <a href="register.html" id="logoutButton" onclick="logoutUser()">Logout</a>
        </form>

        <form id="regForm" class="register-form">
            <input id="newFName" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
            <div id="reg-FName-error" class="errorReps"></div>

            <input id="newLName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
            <div id="reg-LName-error" class="errorReps"></div>

            <input id="newUName" type="text" placeholder="Username">
            <div id="reg-UName-error" class="errorReps"></div>

            <input id="newPass" type="password" placeholder="Password"> 
            <div id="reg-pass-error" class="errorReps"></div>
            <div id="passStrength"></div>

            <input id="newEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email">
            <div id="reg-email-error" class="errorReps"></div>

            <input id="newPhone" type="number" placeholder="Tel. Number">
            <div id="reg-phone-error" class="errorReps"></div>

            <button onclick="registerUser()">Create</button>
            <p class="loginMessage"> Already Registered? <a href="#">Login</a>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.loginMessage a').click(function(){
    $('form').animate({height:"toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
    });
</script>

<script>

// pre-coded users

var existingUsers = 
[
    {   
        firstname: "Gerry",
        lastname: "Agnew",
        username: "GerryA",
        password: "password123",
        email: "gerry@gmit.ie",
        phone:"0833333333"

    },
    {
        firstname: "Sean",
        lastname: "Duignan",
        username: "SeanD",
        password: "password456",
        email: "sean@gmit.ie",
        phone:"0822222222"
    },
    {
        firstname: "Michael",
        lastname: "Duignan",
        username: "MichaelD",
        password: "password789",
        email: "michael@gmit.ie",
        phone:"0844444444"
    }
]

//function setup()
//{
    // setup functions
//}


function dropdown()
{
    document.getElementById("myDropDwn").classList.toggle("show");
}
username.addEventListener('blur', logUserVerify, true);
password.addEventListener('blur', logPassVerify, true);
newFName.addEventListener('blur', fNameVerify, true);
newLName.addEventListener('blur', lNameVerify, true);
newUName.addEventListener('blur', regUserVerify, true);
newPass.addEventListener('blur', regPassVerify, true);
newEmail.addEventListener('blur', emailVerify, true);
newPhone.addEventListener('blur', phoneVerify, true);

function loginValidate()
{
    if(username == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("login-user-error").innerHTML = "Username required";
        //username.focus();
        return false;
    }       
    if(password == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("login-pass-error").innerHTML = "Password required";
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }       
}

function registerValidate()
{
    if(registerFName == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("reg-FName-error").innerHTML = "First Name required";
        newFName.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(registerLName == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("reg-LName-error").innerHTML = "Last Name required";
        newLName.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(registerUName == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("reg-UName-error").innerHTML = "Username required";
        newUName.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(registerUName.length < 8)
    {
        document.getElementById("reg-UName-error").innerHTML = "Username must be 8 characters or more";
        newUName.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(registerPass == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("reg-pass-error").innerHTML = "Password required";
        newPass.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(registerEmail == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("reg-email-error").innerHTML = "Email required";
        newEmail.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(registerPhone == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("reg-phone-error").innerHTML = "Phone number required";
        newPhone.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
// Event Functions

function logUserVerify()
{
    if (username != "")
    {
        document.getElementById("login-user-error").innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
}
function logPassVerify()
{
    if (password != "")
    {
        document.getElementById("login-pass-error").innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
}
function fNameVerify()
{
    if (registerFName != "")
    {
        document.getElementById("login-FName-error").innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
}
function lNameVerify()
{
    if (registerLName != "")
    {
        document.getElementById("login-LName-error").innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
}
function regUserVerify()
{
    if (registerUName != "")
    {
        document.getElementById("login-UName-error").innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
    if (registerUName > 8)
    {
        document.getElementById("login-UName-error").innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
}
function regPassVerify()
{
    if (registerPass != "")
    {
        document.getElementById("login-pass-error").innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
}
function phoneVerify()
{
    if (registerPhone != "")
    {
        document.getElementById("login-phone-error").innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
}
function emailVerify()
{
    if (registerEmail != "")
    {
        document.getElementById("login-email-error").innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
}   

// Login/Register Functions

function loginUser()
{
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    for (i = 0; i < existingUsers.length; i++)
    {
        if(username == existingUsers[i].username && password == existingUsers[i].password)
        {
            alert(username + " Is logged in");
            document.getElementById("loggedIn-Out").innerHTML = username;
            document.getElementById("login-user-error").innerHTML = "";
            localStorage.user = username;
            localStorage.pass = password;
            return;
        }
        else if(username != existingUsers[i].username)
        {
            document.getElementById("login-user-error").innerHTML = "Invalid, user does not exist";
            username.focus();
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            loginValidate();
        }   
    }
}

function logoutUser()
{
    localStorage.removeItem("user");
    localStorage.removeItem("pass");
    document.getElementById("loggedIn-Out").innerHTML = "Login/Register";
}

function registerUser()
{
    var registerFName = document.getElementById("newFName").value;
    var registerLName = document.getElementById("newLName").value;
    var registerUName = document.getElementById("newUName").value;
    var registerPass = document.getElementById("newPass").value;
    var registerEmail = document.getElementById("newEmail").value;
    var registerPhone = document.getElementById("newPhone").value;

    localStorage.regFname = registerFName;
    localStorage.regLname = registerLName;
    localStorage.regUname = registerUName;
    localStorage.regPass = registerPass;
    localStorage.regMail = registerEmail;
    localStorage.regPhone = registerPhone;

    var newUser =
    {
        firstname: registerFName,
        lastname: registerLName,
        username: registerUName,
        password: registerPass,
        email: registerEmail,
        phone: registerPhone
    }

    for(i = 0; i < existingUsers.length; i++)
    {

        if(registerUName == existingUsers[i].username)
        {
            document.getElementById("reg-UName-error").innerHTML = "Username already exists";
            newUName.focus();
            return false;
        }

        if(registerEmail == existingUsers[i].email)
        {
            document.getElementById("reg-email-error").innerHTML = "Email already exists";
            newEmail.focus();
            return false;
        }
        registerValidate();
    }
    existingUsers.push(newUser);
}
// Password Strength functions

function passwordStr()
{
    var passValue = document.getElementById("newPass").value;

    if(passValue.length >= 8 && passValue.length <= 10)
    {
        document.getElementById("passStrength").innerHTML = "Weak";
    }
    else if(passValue.length > 10 && passValue.length <= 16)
    {
        document.getElementById("passStrength").innerHTML = "Average";
        document.getElementById("passStrength").style.color = "yellow";
    }
    else if(passValue.length > 16)
    {
        document.getElementById("passStrength").innerHTML = "Strong";
        document.getElementById("passStrength").style.color = "green";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("passStrength").style.color = "red";
    }
}
var passInput = document.getElementById("newPass");
passInput.addEventListener("input", passwordStr);

</script>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the problem you experience. Also consider editing your code example to provide a [mcve]. You could also use sites like jsfiddle etc. to allow others to test and edit your code directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a type attribute to your login button. `type="button"`

```
<button type="button" onclick="loginUser()">Login</button>
```

Without specifying a type, the button will default to `submit` behavior. You seem to be handling the login without default form submission, so setting the type to button just changes it to a regular button hence no form submission.

Comment: Great! This solved at the very least a handful of issues. Thank you!

Comment: @CuanOCon here in Stack overflow, if an answer mets your needs, we mark the answer as accepted to grant a 'bonus' for the people who helped you. Please, make it for this answer checking the 'V' below the answer vote count.